# Old and current location in single row

Tags: oracle

Given table:

```
empid empname location flag
1     kumar    Hyd      old
1     kumar    Chennai  current
2     mani     warangal  current
```

I want to display the records in below format

```
empid empname oldlocation currentlocation
 1     kumar   Hyd           Chennai     
 2     mani      -            warangal
```

Please help me in designing a query to fetch the records in above format.

Comment: Can you assume that there is at most one `current` and at most one `old` row per `empid`?  If there can be multiple `old` rows, how do you know which prior location to use?

Comment: you can check the answer dear for the two cases i described in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one you will get your desired result this in case when you have one old flag per empid .

```
select curr.empid,curr.empname,
nvl(old.oldlocation,'-') oldlocation,curr.current_location
from
  (
   select empid,empname,location oldlocation
   from empd where flag='old'
  ) old,
  (
   select empid,empname,location current_location
   from empd where flag='current'
  ) curr
where old.empid(+)=curr.empid;
```

And if you are having multiple old as flag value against a empid then you can use the below given query which will give the current as well as the most recent old location.

```
select xz.empid,xz.empname,xy.oldloc,xz.currloc
from(
  select empid,empname ,location oldloc
  from 
    (
       select empid,empname,location,flag,
       row_number() over (partition by empid order by rowid desc) rnk 
       from empd 
     ) where rnk=2) xy,
 (
  select empid,empname ,location currloc
  from 
    (
        select empid,empname,location,flag,
        row_number() over (partition by empid order by rowid desc) rnk 
        from empd 
     ) where rnk=1)xz
   where xy.empid(+)=xz.empid;
```